# Error when using IF condition to access data is public class (Error: too few arguments in function call)

Tags: c++

Below is my source code using MS C++ 2010 Express Edition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// declaration section
class Boxoffice
{
  private:
    string title;
    string releaseDate;
    string rating;
    int runningTime;

  public:
    Boxoffice(string =" ", string =" ", string =" ", int =1);    
    string getTitle(string);
    string getDate(string);
    string getRating(string);
    int getTime(int);
    void setBoxoffice(string, string, string, int);
    void displayBoxoffice(void);

};
//========================
Boxoffice::Boxoffice(string movieTitle, string date, string rate, int time)
{
    title = movieTitle;
    releaseDate = date;
    rating = rate;
    runningTime = time;
}


string Boxoffice::getTitle(string movieTitle)
{
    title = movieTitle;
    return title;
}

string Boxoffice::getDate(string date)
{
    releaseDate = date;
    return releaseDate;
}

string Boxoffice::getRating(string rate)
{
    rating = rate;
    return rating;
}

int Boxoffice::getTime(int time)
{
    runningTime = time;
    return runningTime;
}

void Boxoffice::setBoxoffice(string movieTitle, string date, string rate, int time)
{
    title = movieTitle;
    releaseDate = date;
    rating = rate;
    runningTime = time;
}

void Boxoffice::displayBoxoffice(void)
{
    cout<<"Boxoffice title is: "<< title<<endl
        <<"Boxoffice released date is: "<<releaseDate<<endl
        <<"Boxoffice rating is: "<<rating<<endl
        <<"Boxoffice running time is: "<<runningTime<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    //ARRAY (hard code)=========================================
    Boxoffice boxoffice[5];
    boxoffice[0].setBoxoffice("name_a","date_a","rating_a",100);
    boxoffice[1].setBoxoffice("name_b","date_b","rating_b",100);
    boxoffice[2].setBoxoffice("name_c","date_c","rating_c",100);
    boxoffice[3].setBoxoffice("name_d","date_d","rating_d",100);
    boxoffice[4].setBoxoffice("name_e","date_e","rating_e",100);

    //=====================================================
                string input;
                cout<<"Enter date : "; //read input - release date
                cin>>input;
                for(int i =0; i<5; i++) //traverse
                {
                    if(input == boxoffice[i].getDate()) //error here , to compare input and data stored in array
                    {
                        boxoffice[i].displayBoxoffice();//display movie that matches the release date entered.
                    }
                else{
            cout<<"Invalid input.";
                }
        }
        system("Pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why does a function named `getDate` ***set*** something? Where is `setDate`?

Comment: You should split your `get...` functions into getters that return something and take nothing as parameters, and setters which return nothing and take something as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your error is that you dont specify argument in the call:

```
boxoffice[i].getDate()
```

you should add some string to call it:

```
boxoffice[i].getDate("date?")
```

but,... why you specify a parameter to a getData function, from its name it should only return date, and it actually should be specified as const. You already have `setBoxoffice` where you set dates.

So I suggest you to change: `string getDate(string);` to `const string& getDate() const;`, and do the same with other get-like methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I found the error I have made. Instead of
   `getDate(string date)`
i should use
    `getDate()`
I shouldn't have set anything in my getters and should set something in my setter
   `void setBoxoffice(string, string, string, int);`